# Why react-intl is not stable when using formatDate with same argument on different computer time zones?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, momentjs, react-intl

I'm getting a timestamp from server

```
const date = 1420070399999
```

that in console yields:

> new Date(date) => Wed Dec 31 2014 23:59:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)

Then apply to it the following permutations (here `moment` is `moment@2.22.1` and `intl` comes as property using `injectIntl` from `react-intl` package `):

```
  const momentSimple = moment.utc(date);
  const momentFormatted = momentSimple.format(dateFormat);
  const defaultFormatSimple = intl.formatDate(momentSimple);
  const defaultFormatFormatted = intl.formatDate(momentFormatted);
  const formattedFormatSimple = intl.formatDate(momentSimple, { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' });
  const formattedFormatFormatted = intl.formatDate(momentFormatted, { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' });
```

When my computer timezone is set to **Toledo, USA** (Central America Time) those variables (starting from second, excluding the first one) have the following values:

```
"December 2014"
"12/31/2014"
"11/30/2014"
"December 2014"
"November 2014"
```

But when I switch to **Tokyo, Japan** I am getting this:

```
"December 2014"
"1/1/2015"
"12/1/2014"
"January 2015"
"December 2014"
```

As you can see there is Dec/Nov in Toledo and Jan/Dec in Tokyo.

**Why is this so?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I found out problem is in the fact that I'm providing the month/year string to `formatDate` method ( e.g. `December 2014` ) that is digested by this method as Midnight of December 2014 in runtime browser timezone, so if I'm in Tokyo, respectful UTC local time month becomes November, as it's *behind* Tokyo.

I should have used `timeZone` option, passed as second argument to `intl.formatDate()` method, like described in [documentation for this method](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#date-formatting-apis) under `type DateTimeFormatOptions ...` declaration. This would force used by `react-intl` underlying `Intl` JS API method `formatDate` to treat date provided as first argument as UTC.

```
  const momentSimple = moment.utc(date);
  const momentFormatted = momentSimple.format(dateFormat);
  const defaultFormatSimple = intl.formatDate(momentSimple, { timeZone: 'UTC' });
  const defaultFormatFormatted = intl.formatDate(momentFormatted, { timeZone: 'UTC' });
  const formattedFormatSimple = intl.formatDate(momentSimple, { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', timeZone: 'UTC' });
  const formattedFormatFormatted = intl.formatDate(momentFormatted, { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', timeZone: 'UTC' });
```